# How to get X-year low price of a stock with Google Finance using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I can currently get the `52-week low` of a stock by using this call in `Google Sheets`.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","low52")
```

How do I get the 3-year and 5-year low of a stock?
For a `3-year` low I tried something like this:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",TODAY(),=EDATE(TODAY(),-12*3))
```

However this returns a list of the past 20 prices, not a single value representing the lowest value over the past X-years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get daily price data for your date range and find the mininum value

For 3-year low:

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-3,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))
```

and for 5-year low:

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-5,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))
```

Dynamically, add your number of years to a cell (for example `A1`) and use:

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-A1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))
```

Note for this pair the 3-year and 5-year lows are the same

#### Formulae Used:

- [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en)
- [MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017?hl=en)
- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)
- [DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en)
- [TODAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en)
- [YEAR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385)
- [MONTH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385)
- [DAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093040?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted - thank you!

Comment: Getting errors with this formulae as of now.

Comment: For dynamical formula extrapolation, I would suggest fixating the cell with the number of years `$A$1`: `=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("NYSE:UBER","price",DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-$A$1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())), TODAY()),0,2))`. This allows you to apply the formula on multiple tickers without adjusting it.